# good practices __unicode__(self)

Tags: python, string, unicode

What is the good practice to solve this easy question?

```
def __unicode__(self):
    return unicode(self.typePlace + " " + self.name)
```

TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'TipoLugar' and 'str'

Comment: What do you mean by "good practice"? This question is not that common.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use string formatting instead of composition, which is both more efficient and will stringify your elements for you as well:

```
return u"%s %s" % (self.typePlace, self.name)
```

Comment: perfect, that's I tried to ask, I made myself misunderstanding.

Answer (score 6):

Presumably `typePlace` is itself an object with its own `__str__()` and/or `__unicode__()` functions (if it isn't, and it's a custom class, then you should add those methods).  So, cast `typePlace` to a unicode string before use:

```
return unicode(unicode(self.typePlace) + " " + self.name)
```